# React navigation issue trying to hide bottom tab navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to make the bottom tab hidden when I navigate to messages room screen, I have tried to use modal but couldnt get it to work .... below is my code, it will be much appreciated if I get some help

Here is my root navigation

```
  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      theme={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}
    >
      <RootNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name='Root' component={BottomTabNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and below here is also the bottom tab navigation

```
export default function BottomTabNavigator() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator
      initialRouteName='Listing'
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: Colors[colorScheme].tint,
        showLabel: false,
      }}
    >
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name='Messages'
        component={TabtwoNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name='ios-chatboxes' color={color} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name='MyListing'
        component={TabFourNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name='ios-albums' color={color} size={30} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

example of one of the tab navigators are below

```
function TabtwoNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabTwoStack.Navigator>
      <TabTwoStack.Screen name='Messages' component={MessagesScreen} />
      <TabTwoStack.Screen name='MessagesRoom' component={MessagesRoomScreen}/>
    </TabTwoStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: Since the user will have to navigate back eventually to the tab screen(using the back button) would it make more sense to have MessagesRoom at the top level Stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab will always show if you place the `MessagesRoomScreen`in BottomTab Navigator. The workaround can be like

```
function RootNavigator() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      .....
      <!-- Add `MessagesRoom` screen here in parent navigator and remove from `TabtwoNavigator` -->
      <Stack.Screen name='MessagesRoom' component={MessagesRoomScreen}/>    
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked but it wasnt suitable for what I wanted but I found using useLayOutEffect hook did the job for me.... thanks for the help